# How to add a alt to a icon tag which has a href?

Tags: html, css, icons, href, alt

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" alt = "Error: Didn't Load" ></i></a>
```

Basically want to make sure that if the icon doesn't load l can still load a alternate text to link to the link l want it to.

Icon is from font awesome

Comment: You can't. `alt` only applies to images and this is not.

Comment: Regardless, you should be using text in your link (even if hidden for most people) as screenreaders will get nothing from your current HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

<a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>

<span class="sr-only">twitter</span>
```

use this **span** tag instead alt, it will work when fontawesome not working...